# Problem with django after installing anaconda

Tags: python, django, anaconda, virtualenv

I am working on a Django project and this is what I am getting when I try to run the server. It used to work totally fine but I think the path is missing for virtualenv. I installed anaconda yesterday and the path variable is changed in advanced system settings. How can I revert them back to original settings? Total python newbie here. Kindly help.

```
C:\Users\13157\django_project>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

C:\Users\13157\django_project>
```

[image: These are my current paths]

Comment: If it worked before, you should already have an environment with django installed. So' you'll have to activate the environment. Did you create an environment using `$ virtualenv env`? [This info](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/venv-win.html) might help!

Comment: I think anaconda installation changed path variables and I created this django app a long time ago. I just want to know how to add the django app path variable again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the virtual environment created that has django installed, do: `path_to_environment_folder\Scripts\activate`.

If you don't have an existing environment, create one by using `python3 -m venv environment` and then activate it with `environment\Scripts\activate`. After that, install django with `pip3 install django`.

Comment: I uninstalled anaconda and installed django restarted my macine and erything is working perfectly. Thanks for your time and effort.